# Creating pdf report from a excel document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a PDF Report using iTextSharp. 
I have an excel sample,which i need to create an exact replica of it in PDF format and use it in that report.The page layout shouldn't be altered.

How am i going to achieve it using c#???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you have Office 2007 or 2010 you can export your file as PDF using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Comment: ..or you can print your file with a PDF printer like [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) which exposes COM objects to drive it inside your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should probably stick to the Office methods mentioned in your question comments.  Using iTextSharp to convert is a huge amount of work because you have to translate sizes, page areas, headers, lines, etc. from the Excel doc and somehow get them into the PDF based objects that iTextSharp expects.  I created a tool to do such a thing for work (because it required special functionality outside of normal "printing"), it took a very long time and it doesn't even come close to being fully featured.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.somehow i feel the same.